# POST array of entities to a property of _Links ? Spring Data REST

Tags: java, angular, typescript, api, spring-data-rest

This is my project entity:

```
{
 "projectName": "prova2",
 "description": "desc2",
 "stage": "In progress",
 "_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/projects/2"
     },
     "project": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/projects/2"
     },
     "employees": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/projects/2/employees"
     },
     "tickets": {
         "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/projects/2/tickets"
     }
   }
 }
```

Now i would like to post an array of employees so that they are associated with the particular project. I also tried with just a single Employee entity.
I tried this in Angular but it's not adding them, i also tried to add just one Employee or multiple with Postman:

```
addEmployeesToProject(employee: IEmployee[], projId: number): Observable<GetResponse> {
    return this.httpClient.post<GetResponse>(`${this.projectUrl}/${projId}/employees`, employee)
  }
```

This is the GetResponse interface in Angular:

```
interface GetResponse {
  _embedded: {
    employees: IEmployee[];
  };
}
```

So how do i add employees to this _embedded.employees: [] collection?

```
{
  "_embedded": {
     "employees": []
   },
  "_links": {
     "self": {
     "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/projects/2/employees"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Add your entities and indicate whether you are adding new or existing employees.

Comment: You want the entities as from spring or angular?